# RStudio Custom Markdown Rendering

Tags: css, r, markdown, knitr, rstudio

I'm trying to use custom markdown rendering in RStudio 0.98 under Linux.
I followed these instructions: https://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/markdown_custom_rendering

My .RProfile look like this:

```
cat("\n Thomas RProfile loaded\n \n")
#From http://blogs/cetis.ac.uk/adam/2013/10/25/changing-style-knitr-and-markdown-in-rstudio/
options(rstudio.markdownToHTML = 
    function(inputFile, outputFile) {
        require(markdown)
        markdownToHTML(inputFile, outputFile, stylesheet='custom.css')
    }
)
```

and can verify it gets loaded.  I also have a custom custom.css in the same project directory.

I'm not sure the custom.css is applied.  I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong.  For example, I click on the "**Knit HTML**" icon in RStudio to knit the document.  Is this correct? Or by doing so it reverts back to RStudio's own rendering of the markdown?

Also are there any alternative sources of custom.css styles that are suitable for R output?
Thanks.

Comment: THere have been a number of changes in the development version of `rstudio` surrounding markdown. See http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/index.html. You can get the development version at http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/preview.

Comment: Thanks @mnel.  I downloaded the preview version and will give it a try.